# Adding or Subtracting Time From Postgres Timestamps

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I am using the following ruby code, with the PG gem, to return a timestamp that is in Postgres "timestamp without timezone" format. Instead of returning the current value, I would like it to return the value (-1 hour).

```
def get_latest_timestamp(id)
  conn1 = PGconn.open(:dbname => 'testdb')
  res = conn1.exec("SELECT MAX(time_of_search) FROM listings WHERE id=#{id}")
  res.values[0][0]
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Postgres, you can add or subtract an interval to or from a timestamp to produce another timestamp, as described [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL).

So in this case, assuming `time_of_search` is a timestamp, you could do

```
"SELECT MAX(time_of_search) - INTERVAL '1 hour' FROM listings WHERE id=#{id}"
```